# execute commands using wix installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

In my Product.wsx I called one bat file which is executed using power shell. Batch file is uninstalling one .exe(differet app) and coping few folders in C:\temp folder.

In web may placess I read calling BAT file from WIX is not good or advisable. IS there any other way to do the same without calling the bat file

```
        <SetProperty Id="InvokeTestPS1"
                     Before="InvokeTestPS1"
                     Sequence="execute"
                     Value ="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -Version 2.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command &quot;&amp; '[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]Upgrade\upgradeMentor3_5.bat' ; exit $$($Error.Count)&quot;" />
        <CustomAction Id="InvokeTestPS1"
                      BinaryKey="WixCA"
                      DllEntry="CAQuietExec64"
                      Execute="deferred"
                      Return="check"
              Impersonate="no" />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="InvokeTestPS1" After="InstallFiles">
            <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
          </Custom>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the folders you are copying, if you know beforehand what each folder is named and you don't need to worry about unexpected subfolders, you can use a `CopyFile` per folder you want to copy. Place them directly under a `Component`. If there's more variability in what needs to be copied, you can write an immediate custom action that adds temporary rows to the `MoveFile` table based on the files/folders you discover you need to copy (and the sane to the `Directory` table as needed).

For the uninstaller, you could call it instead of either `powershell` or the `.bat` file.